# for each json result, add css with class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json

I'm trying to add a color to filter options in my webshop. The color codes are getting saved, now I return them through json. What i'm trying to do is add the color code to the parent class above the input. I found out how to change the class name (which i need for other reasons), but now I must add the color codes in order that json returns them top, down.

Here's what I got so far:

```
    function onDataReceived(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.colorInfo.length; i++) {
            console.log(data.colorInfo[i].colorCode);
        }

        $('input[id^="filter_"]').each(function(){
            $(this).parent().attr('class','addedClass');
            $(this).parent().parent().attr('class','addedClass');
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

            var url = 'myjsonlink.json';
            $.get(url, onDataReceived);

    });
```

The line with console.log(data.colorInfo[i].colorCode); results in the 3 color codes i need #fff etc. Is there a way to insert each of the results above the 3 input types i have?

What i would like to achieve is:

```
<div style="background-color: data.colorInfo[i].colorCode"> <input> </div>
```

something like that

Comment: if you need to add a new class name to the element use .addClass("newClassname") Instead of treating it as attribute.

Comment: My code currently replaces the existing classes, which is what i mean to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onDataReceived(data) {
    //for (var i = 0; i < data.colorInfo.length; i++) {
    //    console.log(data.colorInfo[i].colorCode);
    //}
    var len = data.colorInfo.length;

    $('input[id^="filter_"]').each(function(i){
        $(this).parent().addClass('addedClass');//attr('class','addedClass');
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('addedClass')
               .css('background-color',"'" + data.colorInfo[i % len].colorCode + "'");
//.attr('class','addedClass');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think my approach would be to get the string with the class names from the DOM element:

```
var classString = $(this).parent().attr('class','addedClass');
```

Then split it, and loop through it:

```
var newClasses = []; //initalize the new classes array
var classes = classString.split(/ /);
for(var a=0; a<classes.length; a++){
    var colorObj = data.colorInfo[a]; //get the relevant color object
    if(colorObj){
        newClasses.push(classes[a] + '-' + colorObj.colorCode); //
    }
}
```

And then replace the old classes with the newly created ones:

```
$(this).parent().attr('class', newClasses.join(' '));
```

Something like that. You might want to test it out first ;)